# One page on Bootstrap 3/Rails site isn't mobile responsive (the others work)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Thanks to the answer to my previous stackoverflow question, I was able to make the bootstrap 3 layout on my Ruby on Rails 4 app MOSTLY mobile-responsive.

However, my `views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` page (aka the login page) isn't responsive. Instead, it looks like this on my iPhone 5s:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is my `new.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Log in</legend>
<%= f.input :email, label: 'Email' %>
<%= f.input :password, label: 'Password' %>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
           <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %>
         </div>

</fieldset>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>

<!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <center><h2>Signing in is easy and secure</h2>
 <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54adc070e4b0c8f53bde4cf9/t/54ecfc98e4b0cc380c7af39a/1429903823657/?format=300w" /></center>
</div>
</div>
```

I added the `viewport` later on in an attempt to fix it, but it still didn't help.

Could the image be too large? If I have to, I can delete it, but would the gray box underneath the email and password fields still look overly skinny like that?

Here is the test deployment if you'd like to try it yourself:
https://wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/

Comment: This might be due to use of `col-xs-6` because the width is decided according to the screen width. So this might happen.

Comment: @learner what should I do instead? i thought that those were intended to specify the relative size of the columns (ex half-and-half of the screen). it does what I want on desktop, so how should I modify the code for mobile (if `xs` is the smallest size)

Comment: `container` or `well` class can do either

Comment: @learner I changed the `col-xs-6` classes to `container-fluid` and it works far better now! please post your comments as an answer so I can accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was my comment suggestion and that helped to you!!!!

> Just change the `col-xs-6` to other class like `container` or `container-fluid`.This is because the `col` class divides gets the width as per the screen size . And we are forcing to make it `col-xs-6` so this change happens to the screen.